# Why does adding class specific operator delete activate allocation elision in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

Starting from C++14 we have [allocation elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation), allowing the implementations to omit calling allocation and deallocation functions. But it was a surprise to me to find what can trigger that kind of optimization in Visual Studio 2022.

In this program

```
struct A {};
bool x = ( delete new A, 0 );
```

there is no allocation elision and both new and delete operators are executed in the assembly:

```
bool x DB     01H DUP (?)

void `dynamic initializer for 'x''(void) PROC
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     ecx, 1
        call    void * operator new(unsigned __int64)
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     rcx, rax
        call    void operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)
        mov     BYTE PTR bool x, 0
        add     rsp, 40
        ret     0
void `dynamic initializer for 'x''(void) ENDP
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ozrW9Meqh

But if one defines class-specific `operator delete` in `A`:

```
struct A {
    constexpr void operator delete(void *p) {
        if(p)
          ::operator delete(p);
    }
};
bool x = ( delete new A, 0 );
```

then allocation elision takes place and assembly code becomes simply

```
bool x DB     01H DUP (?)
```

without any `dynamic initializer for 'x'`. Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/K4GvnrTT5

Why did adding class specific deallocation function trigger allocation elision? What are other known ways to achieve it?

Comment: The first behavior is not valid. The initialization of `x` is a constant expression in C++20 and therefore there must not be any dynamic initialization. Allocation function elision is not relevant here.

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug: https://godbolt.org/z/v9s31jTrG (As the other comment says, this is not allocation elision but constant initialization and it's a transient allocation)

Comment: Thanks, MSVC issue reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Delete-and-New-are-erroneously-not-allow/10550954